# Python parse $ in sys.argv

Tags: python, special-characters, argv, dollar-sign

how can use sys.argv to get a string with special characters $ (dollar).  I just need the input as string.

```
Example:
    for arg in sys.argv:
      print arg
```

if the input is like asd$1234
the result is asd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing to do with Python

Linux changes `$1234` into environment variable, you should use `asd\$1234` or `'asd$1234'`

Comment: with backslash the output is ok, but not with quote.